# WHMCS Smarty: Custom domain price list

Tags: smarty3, whmcs

This is how I can get list of all tld (domain) prices:

`{foreach from=$tldpricelist item=tldprice}
   TLD: {$tldprice.tld} - Price: {$tldprice.register}
 {/foreach}`

Hoever I would like to display prices only for certain tlds which I hold in array:

`{$pricelist=["co.uk","me.uk","org.uk","uk","london","com","info","net","biz","org","name","eu"]}`

I'm very new to SMARTY and I'm sure there should be some simple way of calling `$tldpricelist` only for certain tlds.

Answer (score 0):

try with in_array fucntion. I added a check in your code. If tld will be in your $pricelist array then it will show TLD and prices otherwise not.

```
{$pricelist=["co.uk","me.uk","org.uk","uk","london","com","info","net","biz","org","name","eu"]}

{foreach from=$tldpricelist item=tldprice}

{if in_array($tldprice.tld,$pricelist}
   TLD: {$tldprice.tld} - Price: {$tldprice.register}
{/if}

{/foreach}
```